# Loading HTML from URL

Tags: c#, php

This is my first post so bear with my markup.

What i did was create a C# Programm in which at some point i am loading a HTML and get the href tag from a

```
public void GetAllImagesLinks(string chapterLink)
    {

        WebClient x = new WebClient();


        string source = x.DownloadString(@chapterLink);


        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();


        document.LoadHtml(source);


        foreach (var link in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                    .Select(i => i.Attributes["src"]))
        {

            if (link.Value.Contains(".jpg"))
            {
                ImageList.Add(link.Value);
            }

        }

    }
```

now this works with no problem.

Now i wanted to recreate this in PHP, my code:

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $link = array();
    while (empty($link)) {
        $doc->loadHTMLFile($chapterLink);
        $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

        $imagepaths = array();
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($imageTags as $tag) {
            $link[$i] = $tag->getAttribute('src');

            if (strpos($link[$i], 'jpg')) {

                $imagepaths[] = $link[$i];
                if (file_exists($pathtofile.'jpg')) {
                    $i++;
                    continue;
                }
                file_get_contents($imageSavePath . '/' . $i . '.jpg', file_get_contents($link[$i]));
                $iRemoteFile = $this->getsize($link[$i]);
                $iFile = filesize($imageSavePath . '/' . $i . '.jpg');
                while ($iRemoteFile != $iFile) {
                    file_get_contents($imageSavePath . '/' . $i . '.jpg', file_get_contents($link[$i]));
                    clearstatcache();
                    $iFile = filesize($imageSavePath . '/' . $i . '.jpg');
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the links i get are different!

Site: https://manganelo.com/chapter/pn918005/chapter_0

lets take the first img

Image when i load it from c# OR browser:

https://bu2.mkklcdnbuv1.com/mangakakalot/s2/solo_leveling/chapter_0_prologue/1.jpg

Image when i load it from php:

https://s3.mkklcdnv3.com/mangakakalot/p1/pn918005/chapter_0_prologue/1.jpg  (i can't access this img)

It seems to me that there is some kind of protection going on where the links are replaced which makes no sense to me. if they want to protect the site why not remove the entry content rather than only the img links.
Maybe i have to set some kind of headers so that the site sees my request as a "normal" browser request?
I am not sure what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers in first request in PHP with same in c#.  The default haders in c# are not the same as PHP.  Make the c# headers look exactly like the PHP headers.

Comment: I had problems with Wireshark (identefying the right package and headers in that package) so i went back to c# and wrote this: `string headers = x.Headers.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(headers);` but i get only empty messages. I will try wireshark again. gotta lern how it works first.

Comment: You want to look at http messages between the host IP and Server IP.